# Stress tensor is the flow of momentum

Tags: pressure, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Studying fluid dynamic I encounter this definition: the $P_{ik}$ element of the stress tensor is $i^{th}$ component of the momentum flow across an infinitesimal $dS \hat e_k$ surface. What seems strange to me is that if I have a gas at equilibrium than the flow of momentum across any surface is zero because there are the same amount of particle flowing in both the direction. So according to this definition the $P_{kk}$ elements should be zero even if gas pressure is not zero?

Comment: The surface integral over a closed surface (boundary of a volume) of $P$ can be zero without $P$ being zero.